# Deeply nested dynamic templates loses scope of parents

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I'm attempting to use a dynamic template to create a virtual number pad; this works by passing rows of buttons to another template that renders them. The issue I'm having is the template cannot use Templates.parentData() to access the context as it becomes undefined. Moving up in the inheritance by using Templates.parentData(2) or (3) does not function either.

```js
Template.bs_num_pad.helpers({
 'number_rows' : function(){
  var result = [];
  console.log(this);

  console.log(Template.currentData());
        // true
  console.log(Template.parentData(1));
        // Template viewName="Template.bs_num_pad"
  console.log(Template.parentData(-2));
        // true
  console.log(Template.parentData(-3));
        // true
      }
  });

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```html
<template name="bs_num_pad">
 <div class="container bsNumPadNumber">
 <span style="display:block;text-align:center;">{{getBsNumPadNumber}}</span>
 
 {{#each number_rows}}
 <div class="col-3">
  {{>bs_buttonset}}
 </div>
 {{/each}}
 </div>
</template>
```

The number pad template that references another template to generate the bootstrap buttonset.

```html
<template name="bs_buttonset">
{{!Template.dynamic template="bs_buttonset" data=difficultyOptions }}
<div class="btn-group btn-group-md" style="text-align:center;display:inline-block;" role="group">
  {{#each this}}
        <button id="{{btnId}}" value={{value}} class="btn {{btnClass}}" type="button">
          {{#if btnIcon}}<i class="glyphicon {{btnIcon}}"></i>{{/if}}{{#if btnText}}{{btnText}}{{/if}}
        </button>
  {{/each}}
</div>
</template>
```

Template.parentData(-2) should return the contents of optionsModal; instead it returns 'true'.

Comment: Why not just pass in the data context you need in the `data=` parameter (in addition to the `difficultyOptions`)?

Comment: I have tried it a number of ways. Once the template changes it loses scope and that scope of the old context is replaced with the context of the new template. Calls to access the parent are 'true' instead of the actual object.